# Python - Popen(shlex.split(command), shell=False) - not working with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, popen, shlex

I am using `Popen(shlex.split(command)` to run an ffmpeg command which saves out wav files from a quicktime mov file and also save an ffmpeg log file at the same time. if I use this:

```
command = './ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/source.mov -map 0:1 -acodec pcm_s16le -y /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/source_01.wav'

p = Popen(shlex.split(command), shell=False)
```

Then the command completes correctly, but if I add the line which saves out a logfile then it no longer works, so if I use:

```
command = './ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/source.mov -map 0:1 -acodec pcm_s16le -y /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/source_01.wav 2> /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/lofFile.txt'

p = Popen(shlex.split(command), shell=False)
```

Then it no longer works. Using either command in the command line, without python, works fine. If I just use:

```
p = Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Then all works well, but I need to use the `shell=False` for other reasons.

I just can't understand why it breaks by adding the 'correct' end line of `2> /Users/me/Documents/MOVS/lofFile.txt`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the correct syntax `2>`? (Rather than `>2`)

Comment: Your right, sorry, just mis-typed it. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO redirection is provided by the shell, therefore, if you set `shell=False` the command won't be run in a shell, and the `>2 ....` will form part of the command.

Perhaps, as a workaround, you could try using the `-report` option to `ffmpeg`. This will send logging to a file named according to the convention ffmpeg-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.log.